# Scrollviewer concats the textblock and doesnt scroll entirely

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

Hello everyone i am facing a curious functionality of a scrollviewer.

i've got this longlistselector.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ContactsGroupListSelector" Foreground="Black"
                                    Background="Transparent" 
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupsItemTemplate}"  
                                    LayoutMode="List"  IsGroupingEnabled="true" 
                                    HideEmptyGroups ="true"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

and its getting populated with this dataTemplate

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupsItemTemplate">
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">               
                    <Image  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="60" Margin="10,0,8,20"  />
                <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,0,8,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
              <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Name}"  Tap="DisplayTheContactGroupClicked" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0"/>
                 </ScrollViewer>
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu Background="#FF2A3136" IsZoomEnabled="false">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="White" Header="delete group" Click="Delete" />
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>               
            </StackPanel>            
        </DataTemplate>
```

so the question. The scrollviewer doesnt scroll the entire textblock but only a chunk of it and i cant find out why.
If i set the StackPanel's orientation to Vertical it works as intended, but not in horizontal. Why?

Comment: are you giving height of TextBlock ? if not try it out

Comment: thanks for the quick response, its a horizontal Stackpanel/scrollviewer so i had to set a width for the scrollviewer. now it works as intented, thank you.

Comment: Maybe share a screen shot to help visualize the issue. In the meantime though have you tried replacing the stackpanel with a Grid with 3 columns instead'

Comment: it was just a child parent issue. when i setted up the scrollviewer to have a proper width the problem was solved.